# Dynamically infer Schema of returned object from UDF in pySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to use a UDF in pySpark which doesn't return an atomic value but a nested structure.
I know that I can register the UDF and manually set the schema of the object it will return, e.g.

```
format = ArrayType(
                   StructType([
                               StructField('id',IntegerType()),
                               StructField('text',StringType())
                              ]
                  )
spark.udf.register('functionName', functionObject, format)
```

and use python lists inside the UDF to match the format, e.g.

```
return [[1,'A'],[2,'B']]
```

but is there any way to avoid explicitly setting the return type when registering the UDF, and instead automatically infer its schema?

If I don't set a return type, it is automatically set to `StringType`.

Answer (score 2):

> is there any way to avoid explicitly setting the return type when registering the UDF, and instead automatically infer its schema?

There is not. Schema has to be known before udf is called and it cannot be inferred on runtime.

Comment: But the schema is not known when I read with spark-xml, csv, etc, and it is inferred at runtime. Is there no such function that I can use for my UDF? How do the spark readers infer the schema?